# Why is the Lorentz field larger than the external field in isotropic, linear and homogeneous dielectrics?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

The definition of the Lorentz field is to apply an external electric field $\mathbf{E}$ on the isotropic, linear and uniform dielectric. At this time, a vacuum ball is assumed inside the dielectric, and the electric field at the position of the vacuum ball is the Lorentz field $\mathbf{E}_L$. The relationship between the two is:
$$
\mathbf{E}_L = \mathbf{E} + \dfrac{\mathbf{P}}{3\varepsilon_0}
$$

where $\mathbf{P}$ is electric polarization. My question is, $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{E}_L$, $\mathbf{P}$ are all in the same direction, so $|\mathbf{E}_L|$ is greater than $|\mathbf{E} + \dfrac{\mathbf{P}}{3\varepsilon_0}|$, why the applied electric field is greater than the electric field inside the dielectric, which confuses me, no A depolarizing field should be created such that the internal electric field is smaller than the applied electric field.
Where is the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a common misunderstanding, and the fault is mostly in how difficult this topic actually is.

There are too many electric fields involved, so you really need to be extremely clear about which particular one we are talking about. What you call the external electric field is actually not.

I am going to use this particular resource, because not only does it label everything clearly, but that it also discusses precisely the question you are confused about: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/elmat_en/kap_3/backbone/r3_2_6.html

Your $\vec E_L$ is his $\vec E_\text{loc}$, the locally felt field. His $\vec E_L$ is the field due to the spherical surface choice of Lorentz. Again, I will be using his naming, because it is much clearer than yours.
$$\vec E_\text{loc}=\vec E_\text{ex}+\vec E_\text{pol}+\vec E_L+\vec E_\text{near}\tag1$$
$$\vec E_\text{ex}=\frac Vd\tag2$$
$$\vec E_\text{pol}=-\frac{\vec P}{\epsilon_0}\tag3$$
$$\vec E_L=+\frac{\vec P}{3\epsilon_0}\tag4$$
$$\vec E_\text{near}=\vec0\tag{by assuming simple cubic symmetry}$$
Now, if you want to talk about externally applied field, only Equation (2) will make sense. You have also corrected stated that the polarisation $\vec P$ points in the same direction as the externally applied field $\vec E_\text{ex}$ in the assumption of a uniformly polarised material *aligned with the externally applied field.* You are even correct that, if you do that, then the polarisation should act to reduce the field felt inside the material, and that is Equation (3).
$$\vec E_\text{loc}=\vec E_\text{ex}-\frac{\vec P}{\epsilon_0}+\frac{\vec P}{3\epsilon_0}+\vec0=\vec E_\text{ex}-\frac{2\vec P}{3\epsilon_0}\tag{1 substituted}$$
This is the expression that you will get if you take the field relative to the external field. You can see that it is actually less than the externally applied field. How, then, do we get the other expression?

Well, the answer is that we also have to consider **old** Maxwellian fields. By definition,
$$\vec E_o=\vec E_\text{ex}+\vec E_\text{pol}\tag5$$
$$\vec E_\text{loc}=\vec E_o+\vec E_L+\vec E_\text{near}=\vec E_o+\frac{\vec P}{3\epsilon_0}\tag6$$
and we recover the formula you were using. Really, this means that your external field is actually just the old Maxwellian field, and it also explains why it is somewhat ok to expect that the real field is slightly bigger than the Maxwellian averaged field. We can thus see that your question actually comes from inconsistent use of symbols. You simply needed to be more careful in the definitions of the stuff flying around, and there are indeed too many things to consider!

---

Personally, I think that the whole Maxwellian invocation of averaged fields is a crazy hack that is really bad for the conceptual understanding of the subject. But alas, we have to work with stuff that people have already done a lot of prior work on.

You should also read the yellow highlighted part in that document, because he specifically says that the average field is different from the locally felt field at least in the fact that you removed one charge/dipole in the locally felt field, whereas the averaged field contains everything. A dipole in the system you are considering as the locally felt field really should not be feeling the field due to itself!

Another way to do it is to realise that the real electric field inside a material should be fluctuating up and down based upon position; if you are at an empty space, you should not be seeing as much of an electric field as exactly at an ion. The average is thus going to be smaller than the actual field felt at an ion that is contributing to the average field. See Figure 3 of https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2014_Dielectric_Properties_of_Insulators.pdf

Note also that the factor of 1/3 is really coming from Lorentz's choice of using a sphere. If you choose a slab that is also aligned with the external field, then in Equation (4) the 3 will disappear, and then in Equation (1 substituted) the locally felt field will exactly equal that of the externally applied field. We might hope for the near field to save the day, but it should impress upon you that there are serious headaches in all these things. And very few actual materials are describable by simple cubic lattices; at least cover BCC, FCC and HCP to get a better idea of how things actually behave.

Just be aware that this is a delicate topic with a lot of known skeletons. If you intend to go into a study of this, you should look up TC Choy's Effective Medium Theory book, which goes into detail how this scheme cannot be correct, based purely upon theoretical grounds. However, this scheme tends to give great results despite us knowing it must be wrong.

You should also look up the Modern Theory of Polarisation, which solves the derivation problem in a nicer way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a question about the content of the link you sent, that is whether the depolarization field $\mathbf{E}_{pol}$ is related to the shape. If in an infinite dielectric, is the depolarization field equal to $-\frac{\mathbf{P}}{\varepsilon_0}$? This part of the electric field is different due to different shapes. Is the source of the infinite term in Ewald Sum. thank you very much

Comment: I actually already included that inside my answer. The specific value of $\vec E_\text{pol}$ and $\vec E_L$ both depend specifically upon the geometry of the system, and so it can be really complicated. The value $-\vec P/\epsilon_0$ is specifically for the case as in between flat capacitor plates and aligned to it---if you simply tilt the dielectric to misalign it, that value will be wrong. 本來就很麻煩。The Ewald sum is another headache that should be unrelated to this.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your answer. 谢谢